# Running java in Windows cmd with all question marks

Tags: java, windows, cmd

```
C:\Users\yanglu>javac
??: javac <options> <source files>
??, ???????:
  -g                         ????????
  -g:none                    ?????????
  -g:{lines,vars,source}     ?????????
  -nowarn                    ???????
  -verbose                   ?????????????????
  -deprecation               ???????? API ????
  -classpath <??>            ???????????????????
  -cp <??>                   ???????????????????
  -sourcepath <??>           ????????????
  -bootclasspath <??>        ??????????
  -extdirs <??>              ??????????
  -endorseddirs <??>         ????????????
  -proc:{none,only}          ???????????/????
  -processor <class1>[,<class2>,<class3>...] ?????????????; ?????????
  -processorpath <??>        ?????????????
  -parameters                ???????????????
  -d <??>                    ?????????????
  -s <??>                    ?????????????
  -h <??>                    ????????????????
  -implicit:{none,class}     ????????????????
  -encoding <??>             ????????????
  -source <???>              ?????????????
  -target <???>              ???? VM ??????
  -profile <????>            ?????? API ???????????
  -version                   ????
  -help                      ?????????
  -A???[=?]                  ????????????
  -X                         ??????????
  -J<??>                     ??? <??> ????????
  -Werror                    ?????????
  @<???>                     ???????????
```

The default language of my PC is English. Can anyone tell me how to solve that?

Comment: What about reinstall the JDK?

Comment: having a look here http://superuser.com/questions/346498/how-do-i-change-my-cmd-exe-to-english

might help you, it suggests using  `chcp 437` command to get it to run in US english

Answer (score 0):

Looks like Java is picking up an Asian language as the default and Windows can't display it.  Not sure why exactly, but you can get Javac to temporarily use US English language by using:

```
javac -J-Duser.language=en -J-Duser.country=US <other arguments>
```

Answer (score 0):

All the advice given is good advice:

1) If you're sure your PC is English - then it sounds like your JDK isn't. Consider getting a known-English [JDK](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/) and installing it instead.

2) Try the [chcp 437](https://superuser.com/questions/346498/how-do-i-change-my-cmd-exe-to-english) command,

... or ...

3) Failing all else, try the magic java [-Duser.language=en -Duser.country=US](http://tiku.io/questions/2601816/javac-and-java-are-in-wrong-encoding-and-locale) incantation.